# Detecting change in Network type (TelephonyManager) in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want my app to automatically notify the user when the `networkType` changes(eg from `EDGE` to `3G` or `3G` to `1XRTT` etc). 
Using the `getNetworkType()` method, I have to continuously check for a change in `networkType`. Is there some kind of intent being broadcasted throughout the system when a change is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ConnectivityManger.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION [Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

From Documentation

> A change in network connectivity has occurred. A default connection has either been established or lost. The NetworkInfo for the affected network is sent as an extra; it should be consulted to see what kind of connectivity event occurred.